# next.js project Invalid escape sequence in template error for css block

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im doing some practices for one of my future work projects with Next.js and i am ready to finish this step of practise. But i have an error. Im trying to create some css codes in my page file but i always have this "Invalid escape sequence in template error for css block" syntax error. Can anyone help me?

And sorry about the mess of my code. I still haven't finished writing it. And for now css section is much more like placeholder. I'll write my css once I am able to get rid of this error.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../../../components/Layout';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import RequestHelper from '../../../utils/request';
//import { SOCIABLE_WEB_USER_TOKEN } from '../../../constants';
import { getUserDecryptedToken, getUserDecryptedProfile } from '../../../utils/auth';
//import '.index.css';


import { withTranslation } from '../../../i18n'

class Deletion extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ query }) {

        const token = getUserDecryptedToken();
        const user = null;
        
        
        //const restrictionReasons = await RequestHelper.getAsync(`${process.env.apiURL2}/api/user/restrictionReasons?userId=${user.id}&token=${token}`);
        const restrictionReasons = { "success": true, "message": "", "payload": { "photos": [{ "url": "https://sociableImagesDebug.b-cdn.net/profilepics/zvt76x78lqbyykbnsn2zg.jpg" }], "postPhotos": [{ "type": "photo", "url": "https://sociableImagesDebug.b-cdn.net/newsFeedpics/6rcnjhix2verflwvicp9li-post-m.jpg" }, { "type": "photo", "url": "https://sociableImagesDebug.b-cdn.net/newsFeedpics/vqmcr57ielg2lj9ny4ghag-post-m.jpg" }, { "type": "video", "url": "https://sociableVideosDebug.b-cdn.net/9qt0mvgvuwk7arnf8acvmb" }, { "type": "video", "url": "https://sociableVideosDebug.b-cdn.net/3ts2x692y3dkjmujsosexn" }] } };
        const { success, payload, message } = restrictionReasons;
        if (success) {
            return {
                success,
                payload
            }
        }
        else {
            return {
                payload: {
                    photos: [],
                    postPhotos: []
                }, success, message
            }
        }
    }

    constructor(args) {
        super(args);

        this.state = {
            showConfirmDialog: false,
            confirm: false,
            warning: false,
            warnMessage: '',
            requestSuccess: false,
            requestFail: false
        }
    }

    onClickForCheckbox() {
        this.setState({
            warning: false,
            warnMessage: '',
            confirm: !this.state.confirm
        });
    }

    onClickForDelete() {
        this.setState({
            showConfirmDialog: !this.state.showConfirmDialog
        });
    }

    async onClickForConfirmAndDelete() {
        const { confirm } = this.state;
        const { t } = this.props;
        if (confirm) {

            
            ///cors/executer
            const removeRestriction = {"success": true, "message": "Engel kaldırıldı"};
            console.log("ss", removeRestriction);
            const success = removeRestriction.success;

            if (success)
                this.setState({
                    requestSuccess: true,
                    requestFail: false,
                    showConfirmDialog: false
                })
            else
                this.setState({
                    requestSuccess: false,
                    requestFail: true,
                    showConfirmDialog: false,
                })
        }
        else
            this.setState({
                warning: true,
                warnMessage: t('common:confirm_user_restriction')
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { t, payload, success, message } = this.props;
        const { postPhotos, photos } = payload;
        const { requestSuccess, requestFail } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
          <Layout
                head={{
                    title: t('common:title_user_restriction') + " - " + t('motto'),
                    type: 'website'
                }}>
                {requestSuccess == true && requestFail == false ? <React.Fragment>
                    <div className="content text-center">
                        <div className="dq">
                            <div className="fh" />
                            <div className="fk">
                                <ul className="ca bqe bqf agk">
                                    <li className="tu b ahx2" style={{ marginBottom: 12 }}>
                                        <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                                            {t(`common:user_restriction_your_account_unblocked`)}
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
                    :
                    success != true ?
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <div className="by ahy">
                                <div className="dq">
                                    <div className="fh" />
                                    <div className="fk">
                                        <ul className="ca bqe bqf agk">
                                            <li className="tu b ahx2" style={{ marginBottom: 12 }}>
                                                <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                                                    {t(`common:${message}`)}
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                        :
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <div className="by ahy">
                                <div className="dq">
                                    <div className="fh" />
                                    <div className="fk">
                                        <ul className="ca bqe bqf agk">
                                            <li className="tu b ahx2" style={{ marginBottom: 12 }}>
                                                <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                                                    <div className="dont-break-out">
                                                        <center>
                                                            <h4 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('common:desc_user_restriction') }} />
                                                        </center>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <br />
                                                    {photos.length > 0 && postPhotos.length > 0 &&
                                                        <div className="" x-ms-format-detection="none">
                                                            <p>{t('common:desc1_user_restriction')}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    }
                                                    <br />
                                                    <div className="">

                                                        {photos.length > 0 &&
                                                            <div className="rp bra brb agk">
                                                                <div className="rq">
                                                                    <h6 className="agd">{t('photos_title')}</h6>
                                                                    <div className="grid-list-wrapper-wide">
                                                                        {photos.map((x, i) =>
                                                                            <div key={i} className="profile-photos-photo-item-wide">
                                                                                <img className="profile-photos-photo-item-img-wide" src={x.url} />
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        )}
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        }

                                                        {postPhotos.length > 0 &&
                                                            <div className="rp bra brb agk">
                                                                <div className="rq">
                                                                    <h6 className="agd">{t('post_photos_title')}</h6>
                                                                    <div className="grid-list-wrapper-wide">
                                                                        {postPhotos.map((x, i) =>
                                                                            <div key={i} className="profile-photos-photo-item-wide">
                                                                                {x.type == "photo" ?
                                                                                    <img className="profile-photos-photo-item-img-wide" src={x.url} />
                                                                                    :
                                                                                    <video controls controlsList="nofullscreen nodownload noremoteplayback foobar" className="profile-photos-photo-item-img-wide" >
                                                                                        <source src={x.url} />
                                                                                    </video>
                                                                                }
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        )}
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        }

                                                    </div>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <div className="">
                                                        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('common:desc2_user_restriction') }} />
                                                        <center>
                                                            <button
                                                                className="cg pq pz active"
                                                                onClick={this.onClickForDelete.bind(this)}>{t('common:button_confirm_user_restriction')}</button>
                                                        </center>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <br />
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <Modal
                                show={this.state.showConfirmDialog}
                                onHide={() => this.setState({ showConfirmDialog: false })}>
                                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                    <h5><center>{t('common:title_user_restriction')}</center></h5>
                                </Modal.Header>
                                <Modal.Body style={{ "padding": "0px" }}>
                                    <ul className="ca bqe bqf agk">
                                        <li key="postWriteAre" className="tu b ahx" style={{ marginBottom: "12px", marginBottom: '0px', border: '1px solid transparent' }}>
                                            <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                                                <div className="">
                                                    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('common:desc2_user_restriction2') }} />
                                                    <div className="checkbox">
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onClickForCheckbox.bind(this)} value={this.state.confirm} />
                                                            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('common:button_user_restriction') }} />
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                {this.state.warning &&
                                                    <div className="">
                                                        <br />
                                                        <center>
                                                            <span style={{ color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{this.state.warnMessage}</span>
                                                        </center>
                                                        <br />
                                                    </div>
                                                }
                                                <div className="">
                                                    <center>
                                                        <button
                                                            className="cg pq pz active"
                                                            onClick={this.onClickForConfirmAndDelete.bind(this)}>{t('common:button_remove_user_restriction')}</button>
                                                    </center>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </Modal.Body>
                            </Modal>
                        </React.Fragment>
                        
                }

            <style jsx>{`
  html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 51px;
}

article, aside, footer, header, unused_nav, section {
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

figcaption, figure, main {
  display: block;
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .my-tab-label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .my-tab-label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .my-tab-label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
`}</style>
 
            </Layout>  
</div>            
            
        )
        
    
    
      }
    
}



export default withTranslation('common')(withRouter(Deletion));
```